# Powershell output correction

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to build a PS script (for Office 365) that will help me to manage everyday tasks such as settings Email forwarding for users, adding email etc

i've started with the connection procedure and the i want that powershell ask me for the user name, and run some command and will show me the result so i'll be able to run it through a "menu":

it's working perfect and do what i want, the problem is that for instance if there are two users with the same name like "trevor" the result will show me

trevor jackson and trevor blahblah

How i can make the script to tell me "i've found two users with the same name"?

here is the short version of the code (the connection to the O365 don't need to be here)

```
    $askusername= Read-Host "What is the user name? you can write part of the user name to"

    write-host "`n"

    $checkuser = Get-Mailbox -Identity *$askusername*

    write-host  -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Found this user: $checkuser"

    #menu
$menu = Read-Host -Prompt "
    `n1. Enalbe Email Forwarding from $checkuser to a spesific user WITH copy?
    `n2. Enable  Email Forwarding from $checkuser to a spesific user WITHOUT a copy?
    `n3. Disable Forwarding
    `n4. Exit
    `n  What would you like to do?"
    Switch($menu){
            1{Get-Mailbox -Identity *$askusername* |select name} (for testing)
            2{Write-Host "it's working" green}
            3{exit}
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $askusername= Read-Host "What is the user name? you can write part of the user name to"

    write-host "`n"

    $checkuser = Get-Mailbox -Identity *$askusername*
    if($checkuser.count -eq 1){
        Write-Host  -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Found this user: $($checkuser.Name)"    
    }else{
        $checkuser = $checkuser | Out-GridView  -PassThru -Title "Multiple Users found, please select the correct user."
    }

    write-host  -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue "Found this user: $checkuser"

    #menu
$menu = Read-Host -Prompt "
    `n1. Enalbe Email Forwarding from $checkuser to a spesific user WITH copy?
    `n2. Enable  Email Forwarding from $checkuser to a spesific user WITHOUT a copy?
    `n3. Disable Forwarding
    `n4. Exit
    `n  What would you like to do?"
    Switch($menu){
            1{Get-Mailbox -Identity $checkuser | select name} #(for testing)
            2{Write-Host "it's working" green}
            3{exit}
            }
```

You need a count, you have to check if the result has more than 1 objects. Something along these lines can tell you if there are more than 1.

Edit: Edited your script to give the count and a gridview to select which user you wish to append. Also, you kept using the incorrect variable in your select list, you should use the checkuser var for it.

Comment: Thank alot @svanzundert 

i'am geeting the output for two users to..

`Found multiple users with name: Trevor Tomer.blah
Found this user: Trevor blah Tomer blah


1. Enalbe Email Forwarding from Trevor blah Tomer Tblah to a spesific user WITH copy?

2. Enable  Email Forwarding from Trevor blahblah  Tomer Tblah to a spesific user WITHOUT a copy?

3. Disable Forwarding

4. Exit

  What would you like to do?:`

Comment: I don't really understand if you are asking something or something else. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Nevermind i will do it in some other way :) thanks alot for your help !

Comment: I have edited my answer to what I think you are really asking. A selectable list to get the correct user. Please see above and try it out. You can simply copy/paste it.